# RRAS NAT Monitoring

Tags: networking, monitoring, nat, rras, portmap

I was wondering if I could monitor my RRAS (VPN) users TCP connection.I don't want to sniff data, however I need to log TCP port numbers and timestamps as well as corresponding users and local assigned IP addresses for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log only TCP traffic, I think RRAS can not do that.

Do you try logging service in RRAS? You can configure log level to "Log all envents", then manipulate log file for TCP connection only. RRAS log file is in
`%windir%\tracing`